# Accessing code behind method Variable in aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working in custom detailed view. I have a program page that views all the program. When a user clicks on update button, the user is redirected to manage programs page. The Manage Programs Page contains a method that fetches all the rows from.

```
public string ProgramsDetails()
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str))
    {
        string htmlStr = "";
        SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = " SELECT * from programs where ProgId=@ProgId";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProgId", "1");
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (reader.Read())
        {
            int ProgId = reader.GetInt32(0);
            string ProgTitle = reader.GetString(1);
            string ProgBudget = reader.GetString(4);
            string ProgStarDate = reader.GetString(5); 

        }

        con.Close();
        return htmlStr;
    }
}
```

How can I access a variable from .aspx page? Lets say I would like to access `ProgTitle`.

I have used this method but seems it's not working

```
<%=ProjTitle%>
```

I would like to show the values of each column in there respected text box

```
<div class="cmrs-panel-body no-padding">
        <div class="cmrs-form-inline">
            <div class="cmrs-form-row bordered">
                <label class="cmrs-form-label">Program Code Name</label>
                <div class="cmrs-form-item">
                    <input type="text" name="Code" class="large">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="cmrs-form-inline">
            <div class="cmrs-form-row bordered">
                <label class="cmrs-form-label">Program Title</label>
                <div class="cmrs-form-item">
                    <input type="text" name="Title" class="large" value="<%=ProgTitle %>"> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="cmrs-form-inline">
            <div class="cmrs-form-row bordered">
                <label class="cmrs-form-label">Program Description</label>
                <div class="cmrs-form-item">
                    <textarea class="large"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Normally i would add the html code to method but this is not feasible  so i want to get the variable value and display it in textbox.

```
htmlStr+="<table><tr><td>"+ProgTitle+"</td></tr></table>";
```

Comment: Can you add a portion of your .aspx code where `ProjTitle` is defined?

Comment: <input type="text" name="Title" class="large" value="<%=ProgTitle %>">

Comment: You can't access local variable. Only global variables can be accessed by `<%= VariableName/Property %>`

Comment: @ekad answer should work for you.

Answer (score 3):

`ProgTitle` must be declared as `protected` or `public` in the code behind to make it accessible from .aspx. Change your code as below

```
protected string ProgTitle;

public string ProgramsDetails()
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str))
    {
        string htmlStr = "";
        SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = " SELECT * from programs where ProgId=@ProgId";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProgId", "1");
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (reader.Read())
        {
            int ProgId = reader.GetInt32(0);
            ProgTitle = reader.GetString(1);
            string ProgBudget = reader.GetString(4);
            string ProgStarDate = reader.GetString(5);              
        }

        con.Close();
        return htmlStr;
    }
}
```

then you can access `ProgTitle` in your aspx code

```
<input type="text" name="Title" class="large" value="<%=ProgTitle %>">
```

Comment: This solved the issue but the returned value from database is not getting displayed in textbox.

Comment: Where do you call `ProgramsDetails` method in the code behind exactly?

Comment: No, I mean where do you call `ProgramsDetails` method? Is it in `Page_Load`?

Answer (score 1):

If not using databinding, how about using session and allocate the variable then use it.  On code Behing: `SESSION.START(); SESSION["PjTitle"]=PrgTtile;`
and then in aspx acces it with: `<%= SESSION["PjTitle"] %>`